# Getting "invalid NEW or OLD specification" message when I try to run this

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

The entire question I'm trying to answer is:

> Utilize the travel anywhere database to create a database trigger "hotel_kids_rule" to enforce a business rule. when inserting a hotel_reservation, if the num_kids value is more than zero, then assign the bed_type DQ to the reservation. save the trigger source as a script file.

For example, the trigger will change the bed_type for the following insert statement.

```
insert into hotel_reservation (reserve_no,reserve_date,arrival_date,dep_date,num_adults,num_kids,customer_id,hotel_id,bed_type,rooms)
values(hotel_reserve_sequence.nextval,sysdate,sysdate+5,sysdate+7,1,2,101,19,'DT',1);
```

For example, the trigger will not change the bed_type for the following insert statement.

```
insert into hotel_reservation (reserve_no,reserve_date,arrival_date,dep_date,num_adults,num_kids,customer_id,hotel_id,bed_type,rooms)
values(hotel_reserve_sequence.nextval,sysdate,sysdate+5,sysdate+7,2,0,102,20,'DT',1);
```

---

This is what I have so far:

```
  create or replace trigger hotel_kids_rule
        after insert or update on hotel_reservation 
        for each row
        when (num_kids > 0)
    declare
       new_bed_type varchar2(20);
       new_bed_type='DQ'
    begin
        new.bed_type=new_bed_type;
    end;
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It should be `:new`, with a colon (and it would be `:old` too).

Comment: I still seem to be getting an error for some reason :/

Comment: Same error or different one? Please remember we can't see your screen, we only know what you tell us,

Comment: Sorry. The same one. Do you mind editing the whole code to what it should be? Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `:new.bed_type=new_bed_type;`

Comment: Thank you. Ya I'm getting the same error at `new_bed_type='DQ'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a *before* trigger, so you can set the new value before it is written. Also, the way you access `new` is not ok: within the trigger code, you need `:new.bed_type`; in the `when` condition, you want `new.num_kids`.

This should work:

```
create or replace trigger hotel_kids_rule
    before insert or update on hotel_reservation 
    for each row
    when (new.num_kids > 0)
begin
    :new.bed_type := 'DQ';
end;
/
```

**[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a266cb14ea97cae7856e13dea5fa75b2)** is a small demo.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of your variable needs to be inside the actual code block. And the [assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#CIHHFHJG) is `:=` in PL/SQL, not `=`. If you want the trigger to change anything you also need to create it as a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
create or replace trigger hotel_kids_rule
    before insert or update on hotel_reservation 
    for each row
    when (new.num_kids > 0)
declare
  new_bed_type varchar2(20);
begin
  new_bed_type := 'DQ';
  :new.bed_type := new_bed_type;
end;
```

Note that the `new` record in the `when` condition is used without the colon `:` while inside the code block it needs to be referenced **with** the colon.

Alternatively [initialize the variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#CIHHEIGG) when declaring it:

```
declare
  new_bed_type varchar2(20) := 'DQ';
begin
  :new.bed_type := new_bed_type;
end;
```

Or even simpler without any intermediate variable.

```
begin
  :new.bed_type := 'DQ';
end;
```